# Call Curl to Get Response from another Docker Container Service

Tags: python-3.x, docker, networking, docker-compose, pycurl

I have two separate docker container services. Their container are as follows:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
6fb658bc7acd        api1                     "/bin/sh -c 'gunicor…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp      api1
c57ac1b45c90        api2                     "python3 api.py"         5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp    api2
```

I am writing code in api1, trying to make a call to api2 using `pycurl` as follows:

```
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, "http://0.0.0.0:5000/"+info)
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()
```

I was able to fetch data if I were to run this file along, but whenever I put api1 as a docker container, I am always getting empty reply from `curl "http://localhost:8000/...`. Am I setting my ports wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
version: '2'
services:
  api2:
    build:
    image: "api2"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  api1:
    build: .
    image: "api1"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Also, my `docker-compose.yml` file looks as follows:

Comment: You cannot access a service on `api2` from `api1` using `localhost`.  You should connect to `http://api2:5000` or `http://api1:8000`.

Comment: Hi, I tried calling `http://api2:5000/...`, but I still get `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`. What could've went wrong?

Comment: "Empty reply from server" suggests a problem with your application. That means that `curl` is successfully connecting but is getting an empty reply.

Comment: I'm confused, you say `I am writing code in api1, trying to make a call to api2 using pycurl as follows:` but then you write `curl "http://localhost:8000/...` which is a call from api2 to api1.